# Show $\exists f \ni f(x)^5+f(x)^4+f(x)^3+f(x)^2+6f(x)=x$

Tags: linear-algebra

Show there exists a function $f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ such that
$$
f(x)^5+f(x)^4+f(x)^3+f(x)^2+6f(x)=x,
$$
for all $x \in \Bbb R$.

Using linear algebra, if the 'system' is invertible then such function exists.
I can't recall this theorem.
I'm not sure it is the right approach either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint, ok an extended hint :-): Use the fact that the polynomial $p(y)=y^5+y^4+y^3+y^2+6y$ is continuous and satisfies
the limit constraints 
$$\lim_{y\to\infty}p(y)=\infty,\qquad\lim_{y\to-\infty}p(y)=-\infty,$$
so it must be surjective by the intermediate value theorem. Hence for all reals $x$ there exists a $y$ such that $p(y)=x$.

Comment: Also add that it is invertible!

Comment: Is it? May be? Do we need that?

Comment: But from the question is seems the PO want a function s.t there is an equality for all $x$...I don't understand how this answers the question

Comment: Define $f$ by mapping $x$ to $y$, where $y$ is any solution of $p(y)=x$. Pick one if there are more! No need for $p$ to be invertible.

Comment: @Belgi: I only wanted to give a hint.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen You are right

Comment: But you do want it to be invertible if you want a continuous function $f$.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't understand that this gives a way to define $f$ (+1)

Comment: Correct, @Robert. But I don't think that the OP asked for a continuous function $f$.

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

For all $x$, there exists $y$ such that  $y^5+y^4+y^3+y^2+6y=x$ (because the polynomial has an odd degree).

Let $f(x)=\max\{y\in R|y^5+y^4+y^3+y^2+6y=x\}$

Answer (score 2):

There must be a real root to the stated equation in $x$ because the polynomial in $f(x)$ is of odd degree, and $f$ is assumed to be a real-valued function.